# Assume that SAT ∈ PSIZE, does it imply that NP = coNP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, circuits

Assume that $\mathrm{SAT} \in \mathrm{PSIZE}$, does it imply that $\mathrm{NP} = \mathrm{coNP}$ ?

I think that I've managed to show that if $\mathrm{SAT} \in \mathrm{PSIZE}$, then both $\mathrm{NP}$ and $\mathrm{coNP}$ are contained in $\mathrm{PSIZE}$, but I can't see how does help me. Any ideas ?

Comment: I wonder whether [tag:space-complexity] would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Space complexity is something different. This is *circuit complexity* or *non-uniform complexity*.

Comment: could someone define or ref PSIZE? afaik this is not a real complexity class.

Comment: @vzn: $L\in P/poly$ if and only if $L$ has polynomial circuit complexity ($L \in PSIZE$)

Comment: @Vor ok was guessing that. do you know of a std ref pref book (paper ok if not) that uses it?

Comment: @vzn: Structure in Complexity Theory: Proceedings of the Conference Held at the University of California, Berkeley, June 2-5, 1986 (found googling). But in circuit complexity the class is usually called  "polynomial size circuits" or "polynomial circuits"

Comment: @Vor do you think notation "P/poly" is much more common?

Comment: @vzn: yes, though "polynomial size circuit" is also very used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $SAT \in PSIZE$ then the polynomial hierarchy collapses to the second level:
$\Sigma_2 = \Pi_2$ (see [Karp-Lipton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%E2%80%93Lipton_theorem) ); but $NP=coNP$ (i.e. $\Sigma_1 = \Pi_1$) is stronger (the PH collapses to the first level).